# How to remove the black background from point cloud

Tags: python, opencv, point-clouds

i try to make 3d recontruction using opencv with python.

i use the intruction on the opencv web page

- single and stereo camera calibration
- pose estimation
- epipolar geometry
- depth map from stereo image

and then the point cloud.

you can see the result.

I removed the background from the images but when i load the point cloud i see the black mask to.
My question is how can i remove the mask from the point cloud. I want to plot just a paper with the
the ball (my working area).

original images:

[image: origin.png]

rectivied images + gray and color depth map:

[image: d-p.png]

```
def get_3D_points(self, disparityMap, K1, K2, P2, t=np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])):
    b = get_baseline(P2=P2)
    (
        C1,
        C2,
    ) = get_centers(P2, prnt=True)
    print(" -- baseline {0}".format(b))
    print("C1", C1)
    print("C2", C2)

    fx = K1[0, 0]
    fy = K2[1, 1]
    cx1 = K1[0, 2]
    cx2 = K2[0, 2]
    a1 = K1[0, 1]
    a2 = K2[0, 1]
    cy = K1[1, 2]

    Q = np.float64(
        [
            [1, 0, 0, -cx1],
            [0, 1, 0, -cy],
            [0, 0, 0, fx],
            [0, 0, -1 / t[0], (cx1 - cx2) / t[0]],
        ]
    )

    print("Q\n", Q)

    return cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disparityMap, Q)


def filter_infinity(self, depth, filter):
    """Filter infinite distances from ``PointCloud.``"""
    # filter inf. points
    mask = depth > filter
    coords = self.vertices[mask]
    colors = self.colors[mask]

    mask = coords[:, 2] > coords[:, 2].min()
    coords = coords[mask]
    colors = colors[mask]
    return PointCloud(coords, colors)
```

point cloud:

[image: pcd.png]

Thanks!

Comment: *I removed the background from the images* --  How did you do that?  To me, this looks like you might have made the color (0,0,0) transparent, but some of the background was slightly brighter than black.

Comment: Did you try to convert the image to HSV color channel, then define the lower and upper HSV range for black color?

Comment: @TimRoberts that's what i'm doing to create a mask `h, w = im.shape[:2]; mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8); cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, corners, (255, 255, 255)); masked = cv2.bitwise_and(src1=im, src2=im, mask=mask)`

Comment: That code doesn't determine what region is in the mask.  How did you create `corners`?

Comment: @TimRoberts here [link](https://github.com/doubleII/demos/blob/main/measurement_2D/opencv_2dmeasurement.py) function: `get_contoures`

Comment: That function has an adjustable threshold value.

Comment: @TimRoberts that means, the both images should have same threshold value, correct? I don't understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: This is a matter for experimentation.  The overall issue is that the background color is slightly less black around the unit and so is not being removed.  Play with the thresholds until the background gets handled.